# Display data on its respective sheet/tab if it matches value

Tags: google-sheets

Need your help once again to solve a mystery.

If "CleintList" sheets mention a service then display it on another sheet.

Example:
if it says, "WebDev" then add it to the WebDev sheet.
if it says "SEO" in front of the domain then add it to the SEO sheet.

these values should be copied:
Agency, Domain

Here is the [sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ENYvx9TnrIsN87o2oAwBz2SOHoIdlV6RP07BFs_LYBw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the relevant rows from 'ClientList' to 'WebDev' and other such daughter sheets using `filter()` formulas like this:

`=filter(ClientList!A2:B, ClientList!C2:C = A1)`

The problem is that it appears that your intention is then to manually add data side-by-side with the formula results, and that exposes you to the risk of rows getting misaligned.

Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

You could also consider an alternative way of viewing data by different types: instead of using formulas in several daughter sheets, like you are planning to do now, use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) directly on the 'ClientList' sheet to choose which rows to show.

This approach would let you, and other users, view and edit one particular kind of data, without disturbing others, and without leaving the 'ClientList' sheet. Importantly, filter views let you edit data right there while you are viewing the filtered results.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I am totally getting your point misalignment, but if we add an entry in the last cell, then we do not have to worry about misalignment as we will not be filtering. the purpose was to show data only on that sheet where we are offering a Service, and if I could get away or get to know how to achieve then I can play with the misalignment issue if it arises at any point.

Comment: Added a formula example to the answer, but I recommend that instead of copying the data to daughter sheets this way, you should use **Data > Filter views** as explained above.

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I need for now :) and I am sure now going to look into Data > Filter Views as well .. once again many many thanks